# How to use Vector<> generics in Black berry

Tags: java, blackberry, vector

I am porting android code into BlackBerry..

Below is my android code snippet..

```
 public Vector<InMapping> INMSGMAPPING;
 public Vector<InMapping> getINMSGMAPPING() {
    return INMSGMAPPING;
}
```

The above code giving fallowing error:

```
 generics are not supported in -source 1.3
 [exec] (use -source 5 or higher to enable generics)
```

I know above error happening because Generics are not allowed in BlackBerry..

Is there any alternate that I can achieve the same functionality in BlackBerry.

Thanks.

Comment: Generics is not supported in blackberry.....

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739080/enable-generics-in-blackberry-jde-4-5-0!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [Vectors](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.5.0api/java/util/Vector.html), and [cast](http://www.fluffycat.com/Java/Casting/) to whatever class you want in elements retrieving